# Swift UITableView Cell Selection not working after search result

Tags: ios, swift

My Scenario, I am trying to Implement `UITableview` with custom cell and search option. Here, Search working fine but I cant able to select search result particular row. How to fix this also please check below my code is fine for `search` option Integration. If anything idea about code simplification, Please provide some sample.

My Code Below

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    var searchController : UISearchController!
    let data = ["New York, NY", "Los Angeles, CA", "Chicago, IL", "Houston, TX",
                "Philadelphia, PA", "Phoenix, AZ", "San Diego, CA", "San Antonio, TX",
                "Dallas, TX", "Detroit, MI", "San Jose, CA", "Indianapolis, IN",
                "Jacksonville, FL", "San Francisco, CA", "Columbus, OH", "Austin, TX",
                "Memphis, TN", "Baltimore, MD", "Charlotte, ND", "Fort Worth, TX"]

    var filteredData: [String]!
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        filteredData = data
    }

    @IBAction func searchAction(_ sender: Any) {

        // Create the search controller and specify that it should present its results in this same view
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        // Set any properties (in this case, don't hide the nav bar and don't show the emoji keyboard option)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable

        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

        // Make this class the delegate and present the search
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // number of rows in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.filteredData.count
    }

    // create a cell for each table view row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = self.filteredData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    // method to run when table view cell is tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        print(cell.nameLabel?.text! ?? "")
        //self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
                return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            })
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
```

Comment: Search is OK. But your problem is passing to new viewcontroller. You should create new viewcontroller. And handle data when user select to a specific row and show data on new viewcontroller. https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @sycoi001 the problem is didselectrow after showing search result if I select any row Its not detecting selected cell. but without search result if i select any row Its working. How to fix this?

Comment: Read the post above. The row has been filter after search, so the indexpath will update and it will not understand what is indexpath after search. So you could not select row to view in new viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve this by using below code.

The problem is `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation`

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma I see that dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation was deprecated in iOS 12. Do you know of any other alternative solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 (iOS 12+)

```
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is inside cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = self.filteredData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Update Above Code with Following Code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell:CustomCell =  self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
            cell.nameLabel.text = self.filteredData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhavesh.iosDev. I will check and update here

Comment: No this is not a issue. Its not working. My question after search result I cant able to select from result @Bhavesh.iosDev